# Exception in combination of @DirtiesContext and FlywayConfig bean in integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit4, flyway

I have a problem when adding new test. And the problem is I think related to @DirtiesContext. I tried removing and adding it but nothing works in combination. Test 1 is using **Application Context** as well.

the following two are running together and no issue.

Test 1

```
@ActiveProfiles({"aws", "local"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UnauthorizedControllerTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UnauthorizedControllerTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private Map<Class<?>, List<String>> excludedMethodsPerController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        excludedMethodsPerController = excludedMethodsPerController();
    }

    @Test
    public void contextStarts() {
        assertNotNull(context);
    }

    @Test
    public void controllerCall_WithoutAuthorization_ReturnsUnauthorized() {
        Map<String, Object> controllerBeans = context.getBeansWithAnnotation(Controller.class);

        for (Object controllerInstance : controllerBeans.values()) {
            LOGGER.info("Checking controller {}", controllerInstance);
            checkController(controllerInstance);
        }
    }

    public void checkController(Object controllerInstance) {
        // Use AopUtils for the case that spring wraps the controller in a proxy
        Class<?> controllerClass = AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(controllerInstance);
        Method[] allMethods = controllerClass.getDeclaredMethods();


        for (Method method : allMethods) {
            LOGGER.info("Checking method: {}", method.getName());
            if (!isCallable(controllerClass, method)) {
                continue;
            }

            String urlPrefix = urlPrefix(controllerClass);

            Mapping mapping = Mapping.of(method.getAnnotations());

            for (String url : mapping.urls) {
                for (RequestMethod requestMethod : mapping.requestMethods) {
                    ResponseEntity<String> exchange = exchange(urlPrefix + url, requestMethod);

                    String message = String.format("Failing %s.%s", controllerClass.getName(), method.getName());
                    assertEquals(message, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, exchange.getStatusCode());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private ResponseEntity<String> exchange(String apiEndpoint, RequestMethod requestMethod) {
        return testRestTemplate.exchange(url(replacePathVariables(apiEndpoint)), HttpMethod.resolve(requestMethod.name()), null, String.class);
    }

    private String urlPrefix(Class<?> aClass) {
        if (!aClass.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)) {
            return "";
        }

        RequestMapping annotation = aClass.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
        return annotation.value()[0];
    }

    private String url(String url) {
        return "http://localhost:" + port + url;
    }

    private boolean isCallable(Class<?> controller, Method method) {
        return Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())
                && !isExcluded(controller, method)
                && !isExternal(controller);
    }

    private boolean isExcluded(Class<?> controller, Method method) {
        List<String> excludedMethodsPerController = this.excludedMethodsPerController.getOrDefault(controller, new ArrayList<>());
        return excludedMethodsPerController.contains(method.getName());
    }

    private boolean isExternal(Class<?> controller) {
        return controller.getName().startsWith("org.spring");
    }

    private String replacePathVariables(String url) {
        return url.replaceAll("\\{[^\\/]+}", "someValue");
    }

    /**
     * There must be a really good reason to exclude the method from being checked.
     *
     * @return The list of urls that must not be checked by the security
     */
    private static Map<Class<?>, List<String>> excludedMethodsPerController() {
        Map<Class<?>, List<String>> methodPerController = new HashMap<>();

        methodPerController.put(AuthenticationController.class, Collections.singletonList("generateAuthorizationToken"));
        methodPerController.put(SystemUserLoginController.class, Arrays.asList("systemUserLogin", "handleException"));
        methodPerController.put(ValidationController.class, Collections.singletonList("isValid"));

        return methodPerController;
    }  
    }
```

Test 2

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles({"aws", "local"})
public class RoleAdminControllerAuditTest {
    private static final String DOMAIN_NAME = "testDomain";
    private static final String APP_NAME_1 = "testApp_1";
    private static final String APP_NAME_2 = "testApp_2";
    private static final String ROLE_NAME = "testRole";
    private static final String USER_NAME = "testUser";

    @Autowired
    AuditRepository auditRepository;
    @Autowired
    RoleAdminController roleAdminController;

    @MockBean
    RoleAdminService roleAdminService;
    @MockBean
    RoleAdminInfoBuilder infoBuilder;
    @MockBean
    AppInfoBuilder appInfoBuilder;
    @MockBean
    BoundaryValueService boundaryValueService;
    @MockBean
    RoleService roleService;

    @MockBean
    private SecurityService securityService;

    private static final String URS_USER = "loggedInUser";
    private static final String BOUNDARY_VALUE_KEY = "11";
    private static final String BOUNDARY_VALUE_NAME = "Schulenberg";

    private String auditEventDate = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupTestEnv() {
        // https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/592
        System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.sdk.disableCbor", "true");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        auditRepository.clean();
        when(securityService.getLoggedInUser()).thenReturn(new TestHelper.FakeUser(URS_USER));
        //when(roleService.addRoleToApp(any(), any(), eq(ROLE_NAME))).thenReturn(TestHelper.initRole(ROLE_NAME));
        when(boundaryValueService.findBoundaryValueById(eq(123L))).thenReturn(initBoundaryValue(BOUNDARY_VALUE_KEY, BOUNDARY_VALUE_NAME));
        when(boundaryValueService.findBoundaryValueById(eq(666L))).thenReturn(initBoundaryValue(BOUNDARY_VALUE_KEY, BOUNDARY_VALUE_NAME));
    }

    @Test
    public void addUserAsRoleAdminLogged() throws UserIsAlreadyRoleAdminException, RoleNotFoundException, BoundaryValueNotFoundException {
        User user = initUser(USER_NAME);
        List<RoleAdminInfo> roleAdminInfos = getRoleAdminInfos();
        roleAdminController.addUserAsRoleAdmin(user, roleAdminInfos);

        List<String> result = auditRepository.readAll();
        assertEquals("some data", result.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void removeUserAsRoleAdminLogged() throws RoleNotFoundException, BoundaryValueNotFoundException {
        User user = initUser(USER_NAME);
        Long roleId = Long.valueOf(444);
        Role role = initRole("test-role");
        role.setApp(initApp("test-app"));
        role.setDomain(initDomain("test-domain"));
        when(roleService.getRoleByIdOrThrow(roleId)).thenReturn(role);

        roleAdminController.removeUserAsRoleAdmin(user, roleId, Long.valueOf(666));

        List<String> result = auditRepository.readAll();
        assertEquals("some data", result.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void removeRoleAdminPermission() throws RoleNotFoundException, BoundaryValueNotFoundException {
        User user = initUser(USER_NAME);
        List<RoleAdminInfo> roleAdminInfos = getRoleAdminInfos();
        roleAdminController.removeRoleAdminPermission(user, roleAdminInfos);

        List<String> result = auditRepository.readAll();
        assertEquals(1, result.size());
        assertEquals("some data", result.toString());
    }

    private List<RoleAdminInfo> getRoleAdminInfos() {
        RoleAdminInfo info1 = initRoleAdminInfo(DOMAIN_NAME, ROLE_NAME, APP_NAME_1);
        RoleAdminInfo info2 = initRoleAdminInfo(DOMAIN_NAME, ROLE_NAME, APP_NAME_2);
        info1.setBoundaryValueId(123L);
        info1.setBoundaryValueKey(BOUNDARY_VALUE_KEY);
        info1.setBoundaryValueName(BOUNDARY_VALUE_NAME);
        return Arrays.asList(info1, info2);
    }
}
```

Test 3 (newly added one)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = FlywayConfig.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
@ActiveProfiles({"aws", "local"})
public class BoundaryValueDeltaControllerTest {

    private static final String API_V1 = "/api/v1/";

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private DomainBuilder domainBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private AppBuilder appBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private UserBuilder userBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private DomainAdminBuilder domainAdminBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private BoundarySetBuilder boundarySetBuilder;

    @MockBean
    private LoginUserProvider loginUserProvider;

    @MockBean
    private LoginTokenService loginTokenService;

    @MockBean
    private BoundaryServiceAdapter serviceAdapter;

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    LoginUserInfo loggedInUser;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        clear();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        clear();
    }

    @Test
    public void updateBoundaryValuesFromApi() throws UrsBusinessException {
        Domain domain = domainBuilder.persist();
        App app = appBuilder.persist(domain);
        BoundarySet boundarySet =  boundarySetBuilder.persist(domain);
        User user = userBuilder.persist(domain.getAuthor().getUsername());
        aLoggedInUser(domain.getAuthor().getUsername());
        domainAdminBuilder.persist(user, domain);

        mockReadInfoFromApiUsingApp();

        ResponseEntity<String> response = callUpdateBoundaryValuesFromApi(domain, boundarySet, app);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
        assertNotNull(response.getBody());
    }

    private void mockReadInfoFromApiUsingApp() throws UrsBusinessException {
        BoundaryValueInfo boundaryValueInfo = new BoundaryValueInfo();
        boundaryValueInfo.setBoundaryValueId(10L);
        boundaryValueInfo.setBoundaryValueKey("boundaryValueKey");
        boundaryValueInfo.setBoundaryValueName("boundaryValuename");

        when(serviceAdapter.readInfoFromApiUsingApp(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(new BoundaryValueInfo[]{boundaryValueInfo});
    }

    private ResponseEntity<String> callUpdateBoundaryValuesFromApi(Domain domain, BoundarySet boundarySet, App app) {
        String url = url(API_V1 + "domains/" + domain.getName() + "/boundarysets/" + boundarySet.getBoundarySetName() + "/app/" + app.getName()+ "/updatefromapi/");
        return testRestTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
    }

    private String url(String url) {
        return "http://localhost:" + port + url;
    }

    private void aLoggedInUser(String username) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims();
        claims.put("username", username);
        loggedInUser = LoginUserInfo.parse(claims);

        when(loginUserProvider.getLoggedInUser()).thenReturn(loggedInUser);
        when(loginTokenService.parseToken(any())).thenReturn(loggedInUser);
    }

    private void clear() {
        appBuilder.deleteAll();
        boundarySetBuilder.deleteAll();
        domainAdminBuilder.deleteAll();
        domainBuilder.deleteAll();
        userBuilder.deleteAll();
    }

}
```

Flyway config

```
@TestConfiguration
public class FlywayConfig {
    @Bean
    public FlywayMigrationStrategy clean() {
        return flyway -> {
            flyway.clean();
            flyway.migrate();
        };
    }
}
```

And I am getting below exception while running all together.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java.....

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: Too many connections
---------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08004
Error Code : 1040
Message    : Too many connections

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: Too many connections
```

I am struggling since yesterday's and you might find duplicate but I tried to add the more details today. please guide me here.

Comment: Can someone help me here or I am gonna delete this question because no response on this since morning ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you must add the configuration for flyway

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/xxx
flyway.user=postgres
flyway.password=xxx
```